# Firebase Authentication doesn't work for our App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

When we log out of the app we don't see the sign-in buttons anymore which are provided by react firebase UI  https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react.

We have to close the browser and restart it again so we can successfully login.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[Here's the video explanation](https://www.loom.com/share/291c6d0d5da64d71b2fc55a09179039f)

Has anyone of you experienced that problem already?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Please do a round of research and add information so everyone who reads your question can understand this and able to help. I found a open issue inthe library you mentioned here is the link: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react/issues/59

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.